# iPOJO: identifier uniqueness namespace for @Publishes and @Subscriber

Tags: java, events, inversion-of-control, osgi, apache-felix

i'm building some components using [`iPOJO`'s awesome EventAdmin handlers](http://felix.apache.org/site/event-admin-handlers.html#EventAdminHandlers-Eventpublisherattributes).  the documentation requires a name attribute for publishers and subscribers, acting as a "unique identifier".

what is the scope in which the uniqueness is enforced?

if it's just within my bundle, i might choose something short and sweet, like "`mySpecialPublisher`".  if it's across all bundles enhanced by `iPOJO`, i might choose something more formal, like "`com.mycompany.my.special.publisher`".

Comment: That is a good question, as it is not clear from documentation on how this works. Either handler acts as a proxy, and has it's own unique name in the OSGi container, or it registers a handler/publisher with the provided by you name. Maybe you can test it out both ways, and post a definite answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be globally unique for two reasons:
* it is used as service.pid (which should be unique)
* it's used to compute instance connections (architecture)